# How to fix exception when video.js video is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

Now I used video.js due to play rtmp video on html5.
and video player is on modal dialog.
When I close modal dialog, exception occured. it seems like continue caching.
And I can't open Dialog again.
Please help me how to fix these issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple
vid_obj.reset() should be called before video.js object is hidden.

Thank you.